# How to bind field to a textbox when field value is changed from a different usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Relatively new to WPF.

Wish to do things correctly aka ViewModel design.

I have 2 user controls.

The 1st has a drop-down box which has a list of Job References.

When the user selects one I wish to display the linked up fields.

So, in my 2nd user control I have this markup:

(just the control in question)

```
<TextBox Name="txtFirstName" Text="{Binding Test}" />
```

in the code-behind:

```
public ucJobServiceRequirements()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new ViewModel.JobRecord();
}
```

The code in my 1st user control when the user selects a Job Reference is:

```
public ucCustomerJobDetails()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new ViewModel.JobRecord();
}

private void cboCustomerJobs_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    JobHistory job = cboCustomerJobs.SelectedItem as JobHistory;
    var vm = this.DataContext as ViewModel.JobRecord;
    vm.JobView = InformedWorkerBusinessService.Job.Get(job.JobRef);
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class JobRecord : ViewModelBase
{
    public JobRecord()
    {           
    }

    Job _Job;
    public Job JobView
    {
        get { return _Job; }
        set { _Job = value; RaisePropertyChanged("JobView"); Test = JobView.FirstName; }
    }

    string _Test;
    public string Test
    {
        get { return _Test; }
        set { _Test = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Test"); }
    }
}
```

My ViewModelBase:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    internal void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) { PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop)); }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

and my Model:

```
public class Job
{
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
}
```

Now when the user selects Job Ref:

```
vm.JobView = InformedWorkerBusinessService.Job.Get(job.JobRef);
```

this is invoked (I checked via debugger):

```
set { _Test = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Test"); }
```

So, my Biding appears to be wrong in the UI (I think!) but cannot see what is wrong.

Like i said I am new to all this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines

```
this.DataContext = new ViewModel.JobRecord();
```

in the constructors of both UserControls each create an instance of your JobRecord view model class. Now you have two view model instances without any interaction between them.

Instead of creating view model instances in a UserControl's XAML or code behind, you should create one view model instance in the common parent control (e.g. the application's main window) and let the UserControls inherit the parent control's `DataContext`:

```
<Window ... xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:ViewModel">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:JobRecord />
    </Window.DataContext>
    ...
    <local:ucJobServiceRequirements ... />
    <local:ucCustomerJobDetails ... />
    ...
</Window>
```

---

As a general rule you should never explicitly set the `DataContext` of a UserControl, because that prevents inheriting the DataContext of the parent control.